# What is the Konsole command that locks the screen

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, opensuse, keyboard-layout, screen-lock, konsole

I'm using `OpenSuse Leap 42.1` and I would like to remap my Keyboard. Now, I want to remap one key (The <kbd>Sleep</kbd> key) to lock the screen instead of sending the entire PC to sleep. For that reason, I need the `Konsole-Command` to lock the screen. I Googled and only found commands that works for `Ubuntu/Debian/Fedora/KDE4`, but I was unable to find anything that worked for my `OpenSuse` Version. Would you please provide any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need Konsole to lock the screen? Usually your Desktop Environment provides a shortcut or a way to define one.

Comment: Like I wrote in the question, I want to remap the Sleep-Key on my keyboard to use it as a Screen-Lock. And yes there are shortcuts, Master+L and the Desktop Icon but I want to do it with one key on my Keyboard, the Sleep Key. And for that I need the Command to do it over the Konsole. Or if you can provide me with a even better way, then that one. Greetings Nico

Comment: What DE/WM are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This works on Unity or GNOME.

On Unity or GNOME, you can lock the screen using the command `dbus-send` as follows:

`dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock`

Explanation:

```
The --type=method_call tells dbus-send to call a method.
The --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver tells it the command is in org.gnome.ScreenSaver.
The org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock tells it to lock the screen.
```

Answer (score 0):

For KDE I used:

```
loginctl lock-session
```